# httpurlconnection.getinputstream NullPointerException

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm having trouble using HttpUrlConnection. When I'm using it with url= https://stackoverflow.com/ it works very well. As soon as I use other code for example: url= http://192.168.78.1/index.php it doesn't work and results in a **NullPointerException** . Can you explain to me why this happens ? Thank for helping.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        URL url=new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        connection.disconnect();
        return  stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    TextView tv=(TextView)context.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(s.toString());
}
```

and this is StackTrace from LogCat:

```
1335-1335/com.example.administrator.http E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.administrator.http.Asysnc.onPostExecute(Asysnc.java:57)
        at com.example.administrator.http.Asysnc.onPostExecute(Asysnc.java:15)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you provide your StackTrace from LogCat? We don't know, where exactly you got `NullPointerException`.

Comment: i added LogCat in my post,thanks

Comment: Looking at your stacktrace you can see that the problem is in onPostExecute method, I think that 's' is null, thus s.toString() will not work. Make sure that doInBackground returns correct data, also try to print stacktraces of caught exceptions in doInBackground...

Comment: Just a tip, but you would help yourself by learning how to run your app in debug mode, and set breakpoints in your code. Otherwise you're going to be asking a lot more questions like this.

Comment: I think you misunderstanding the thing which i want ask, I just ask why with some url these code work but with other url (below my post) it return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a `NullPointerException` in `void onPostExecute(String s)` mehtod. This happened, because `String doInBackground(Void... params)` mehtod returned `null`. It returned `null`, because, you got an `Exception` inside this method and your code returns `null` every time when an `Exception` occurs. `Exception` may occur because of different reasons - e.g.:

- connection time out
- incorrect URL
- unreachable server or end-point
- malformed data in the request or response
- lost internet connection
- input/output error
- and so on...

I think, you got this error, because your url http://192.168.78.1/index.php was unreachable by the Android device. Maybe it was in a different network, this address was unavailable in the network, IP was incorrect or something like that, but it's just my guess. I don't have access to your environment, so I cannot debug it.

`AsyncTask` unfortunately doesn't provide you any error handling mechanisms. You can perform null-checks in `void onPostExecute(String s)` method or try to do other "tricks" like that to prevent such situations, but in my opinion, they're just workarounds. If you want to have clean and robust code, you should get rid of `AsyncTask` an re-implement this solution using e.g. RxJava, which has great support for error handling and other useful features. You should be aware of situations, when server in unreachable, because it happens in real life.

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground method, you return null, when an exception is caught. In that case onPostExecute will fail on the line where you call s.toString().

You can:
Update your onPostExecute method so that it can deal with null results, e.g.:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if (s==null) {
        s="";
    }

    TextView tv=(TextView)context.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(s.toString());
}
```

Or you can return something other when you catch an exception in doInBackground, e.g.:

```
 catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "IO exception caught!";
    }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstanding the thing which i want ask, I just ask why with some url these code work but with other url (below my post) it return null

Comment: I think the problem is that with the conflicting URL you are getting some (yet unspecified) exception and your app crashes then. Btw.I also bet that it crashes when you disconnect your internet connection for example... Make sure that your code works also in error situations.